# 14.04: re-enabling unity style notification in unity after xubuntu-desktop install?

Tags: unity, xubuntu, 14.04, notification, notify-osd

Ubuntu 14.04, I installed `xubuntu-desktop` to get access to both Unity and Xfce. However now, in Unity the notifications are messed up: no transparency, sound change and brightness change do not show up, etc... The question is:

How to re-enable the Unity style notification in Unity?

What I did:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall notify-osd
```

But that did not change anything.

I found this question [Unity notifications messed up after installing Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451147/unity-notifications-messed-up-after-installing-gnome) but there is no correct answer.

By the way the rational for this dual desktop environment is in order to have full access to the systray which can not be white listed in 14.04 anymore. However I still run Unity as my main desktop, only log out and login to xfce when I need to interact with the systray (for DavMail for example).

Thanks a lot in advance,

Seb

Comment: The first answer to [Unity notifications messed up after installing Gnome](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451147/unity-notifications-messed-up-after-installing-gnome) worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `xfce4-notifyd`:

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd
```