# Change notification daemon on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, notification, notify-osd

In older versions of Ubuntu, `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service` could be edited to change the default notification daemon.

However changing this file no longer affects the default notification daemon in the newer version. Any ideas on how to change the default notification daemon?

Comment: You sure about file is exist and/or not was renamed?

Comment: sorry stupid question ... better, say please what desktop manager and desktop environment you use?

Comment: @swift, the file was not renamed or moved. The problem is that modifying this file no longer changes the notification daemon. I use the default Unity desktop environment.

Comment: there nice answer by @Magpie:
[Unity notifications messed up after installing Gnome](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451147/unity-notifications-messed-up-after-installing-gnome)

Comment: Ok I got it, Unity, however GDM or LightDM ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems there is no priority or a single setting point to set which freedesktop notification daemon to run. I got such problem with XFCE installed on Ubuntu 14.04.

Unity notification launch `xfce4-notifyd` as it was  the default.

- Check for available notification services, example:

  ```
  $ grep -r org.freedesktop.Notifications /usr/share/dbus-1/services/
  /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service:Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
  /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service:Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
  ```
- Disable non needed ones, leave only the one you want:

  ```
  sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service.disable

  pkill xfce4-notifyd
  ```
- Check

  ```
  notify-send test
  ```

Unity notification style back (`notify-osd`)

Another way, Unity does not launch any default notifications daemon. So you can add the one you like to startup applications. See [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login). I think it's better because it does not affect other desktop session that relays on the service file to start their notifications daemon.

Helpful Reference:

- [ArchLinux Wiki: Desktop notifications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications)

Comment: This looks great, but on my Bionic 18.04 system, the grep line doesn't find any notification services. But I am properly getting notifications. Has something relevant changed in the last few releases?

Comment: Ah - makes sense. My real goal is just to figure out what is showing my notifications these days so I can get it fixed so it can log timestamps and events. Amazing to me that with all the logging going on in Linux, User-visible notifications don't get logged. Any tips? The existing answers on those questions are either old (e.g. for notify-osd) or haven't worked for some other reason.

Comment: @nealmcb, so you are looking for Gnome, Use D-feet tool and check which tool takes `org.freedesktop.Notifications` address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85298/discussion-between-user-dz-and-nealmcb).

Comment: This solution worked today in Ubuntu 18.04 and it was the only solution in order to stop notifications from stealing focus, I am using i3WM and after installing Budgie DE for testing, the notifications started appearing beautiful but stealing focus, which stopped the workflow so I had to do this with the budgie notification service. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To begin need to say that behavior is reason to decide it is incorrect work of NotifyOSD with Compiz or Metacity what depends on your preferences. It can be also result of change desktop manager (alike GDM). So better solution for you will be better details what you want to do and where. "Where" is where your NotifyOSD server have works.

So if your details is Unity solutions is:

```
killall notify-osd
notify-osd
```

or if above trial was unsuccessful so you can try resolve most common environment:

```
sudo apt-get build-deps unity
```

Let's to find answer together.